# hide just the content of anchor tag and add class on media query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a text here in anchor tag which says add to cart but on mobile view I want to change it to fa fa-cart mobile view

```
  <a class="product"><?php echo $button_add_to_cart ?></a>
```

Now this $button_add_to_cart has text Add to cart and a cart(fa fa-cart).
On mobile view I want [image]

on mobile view I just want a cart

CSS :

```
.thumbnail a.product{
background: #00A1CB;
color: #fff;
float: right;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 13px;
text-transform: uppercase;
position: relative;
}
.thumbnail a.product:before {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 16px;
    content: "\f07a";
    top: 5px;
    right: 8px;
}
```

I tried to replace text with:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
.thumbnail a.product{
content:"\f07a";
}}
```

Its not working

Comment: Clear the content value `content:"";`

Comment: But I need to display cart

Comment: Ah :) wrap the text into span element and hide it on mobile view `.thumbnail a.product span { display: none }`

Comment: I cant wrap the whole text as i want anchor tag to be clicked on cart icon

Comment: I don't get it. What would be the problem if your html would like `<a class="product"><span>your text</span></a>`? The icon would stay anyway as it is attached to `:before` against the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution1:**

```
<a class="product desktop-screen"><?php echo $button_add_to_cart ?></a>
<a class="product mobile-screen"><?php echo $cart ?></a>
```

css:

```
desktop-screen{display:block;}
mobile-screen{display:none;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
        desktop-screen{display:none;}
        mobile-screen{display:block}
    }
}
```

**Solution2:** 
using jQuery

```
<a class="product"><?php echo $button_add_to_cart ?></a>

<script>
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var win = $(this);
      var a_tag_text = "add to cart";
      var icon = "<i class="fa fa-cart"></i>"
      if (win.width() <= 479) {
          $(".product").html(icon);
      }else{
          $(".product").html(a_tag_text + icon);
      }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is there anything where I Can just hide content of anchor tag.. I mean hide text "add to cart" on media query?

Comment: @raulxbox with jquey you can do this easily , i'm update solution 2 for understand how! is it solve problem?

Comment: I added span tag <span class="txt-cart"><?php echo $button_add_to_cart ?></span><span> <i class="fa fa-cart-plus fa-fw"></i></span>
@media I did display:none for txt-cart

Answer (score 0):

I have added `span` and removed positioning on the pseudo element, also added text in the `content`. It works for me.

```css
.thumbnail a.product {
  background: #00A1CB;
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail a.product span:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 16px;
  content: "add to cart \f07a";
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .thumbnail a.product span:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 16px;
    content: "\f07a";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <a class="product"><span></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you have just add one another cart button ....and its style give none

like ...
'here put fa-cart icon'

and after

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {

  .thumbnail a.product {
    display:none;
  }

  #cart {
    display:show;
  }
}}
```